# Escribir hosts.allow en otra maquina

Tags: linux, centos7

estoy intentando modificar el archivo hosts.allow desde otra maquina en una intranet, y a pesar que tengo establecida una relacion de confianza a traves de una clave ssh, y que ademas estoy usando el usuario root, aun asi no me permite agregar una nueva linea en el archivo.

me sale el mensaje
bash: /etc/hosts.allow : Permiso denegado

si estoy usando el usuario root, porque me deniega el permiso de escribir este archivo?
el comando que estoy usando es (desde la otra maquina)

```
sudo ssh -p 16000 root@10.13.0.148 echo "#comentario dummy" >> /etc/hosts.allow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando no se está enviando correctamente al host remoto, así que no se está ejecutando como esperas.

Prueba con algo como:

```
sudo ssh -p 16000 root@10.13.0.148 "echo \"#comentario dummy\" >> /etc/hosts.allow"
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracias.. precisamente estaba mal el comando. Ejecute del modo que indicaste, y se modifico el archivo. Solo una pregunta: a pesar que tengo establecida la relacion de confianza con el otro server, me pide igualmente la clave del usuario (roor en este caso) Sabes si se puede pasar algun parametro con laclave para que no la pida? Estoy necesitando automatizar este comando, y necesito que la password se pase de manera automatica.

Comment: A qué te refieres con "Relación de confianza"? Si te refieres a aceptar el certificado del host remoto, eso no tiene relación con la contraseña. ¿Generaste un par de llaves con `ssh-keygen` y registraste la llave PRIVADA en el equipo que ejecuta el SSH? Entonces debería usarla por defecto. Si lo que quieres es suministrar la **contraseña** de forma programática, puedes hacer un `cat` de un archivo que la contenga (con permisos 600 y owner _root_) y enviarle el contenido con un pipe a tu comando.

Comment: si, precisamente  genere las llaves con ssh-keygen y despues las envie al host remoto con ssh-copy-id... de hecho si intento entrar a ese server con el usuario root, no me pide contraseña. Si embargo, al intetar ejecutar de forma remotra el comando, me pide la contraseña. Despues de ingresarla ejecuta el comando sin problemas.

Comment: estaba viendo que existe un programa que se llama sshpass al que parece se puede recurrir para este tipo de casos. Gracias de todas formas por la ayuda